# Sticky HTML elements within nested scroll windows don't render correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the following scenario...

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ybwumx6/)

...if you scroll the outer table a little bit, you'll see that the sticky table headers within the inner scrolling-container actually render ON TOP of the header for the outer scrolling-container.

Shouldn't these two sets of headers exist in separate stacking contexts?

Is there any workaround for this, aside from just hard-coding z-index values? This is just a mockup of what's being generated dynamically, so I'd have to put a lot of plumbing in place to dynamically calculate the correct z-index values to use at each level, relative to all other levels.

No **JavaScript framework** being used here, just **TypeScript** and require.

**HTML Code**:

```
<div class="scroll-container">
  <table class="outer-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Outer Column 1</th>
        <th>Outer Column 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Outer Value 1</td>
        <td>Outer Value 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <div class="scroll-container">
            <table class="inner-table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Inner Column 1</th>
                  <th>Inner Column 2</th>
                  <th>Inner Column 3</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Inner Value 1</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 2</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Inner Value 1</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 2</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Inner Value 1</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 2</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Inner Value 1</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 2</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Inner Value 1</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 2</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Inner Value 1</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 2</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Inner Value 1</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 2</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Inner Value 1</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 2</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Inner Value 1</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 2</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Inner Value 1</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 2</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Inner Value 1</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 2</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Inner Value 1</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 2</td>
                  <td>Inner Value 3</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Outer Value 1</td>
        <td>Outer Value 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Outer Value 1</td>
        <td>Outer Value 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Outer Value 1</td>
        <td>Outer Value 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Outer Value 1</td>
        <td>Outer Value 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Outer Value 1</td>
        <td>Outer Value 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Outer Value 1</td>
        <td>Outer Value 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Outer Value 1</td>
        <td>Outer Value 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Outer Value 1</td>
        <td>Outer Value 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Outer Value 1</td>
        <td>Outer Value 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Outer Value 1</td>
        <td>Outer Value 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Outer Value 1</td>
        <td>Outer Value 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Outer Value 1</td>
        <td>Outer Value 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Outer Value 1</td>
        <td>Outer Value 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Outer Value 1</td>
        <td>Outer Value 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Outer Value 1</td>
        <td>Outer Value 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Outer Value 1</td>
        <td>Outer Value 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Outer Value 1</td>
        <td>Outer Value 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Outer Value 1</td>
        <td>Outer Value 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Outer Value 1</td>
        <td>Outer Value 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Outer Value 1</td>
        <td>Outer Value 2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.scroll-container {
  max-height: 20em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

table.outer-table div.scroll-container {
  max-height: 10em;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1em;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 2em;
}

table.outer-table th {
  background: tan;
}

table.inner-table th {
  background: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one class working for both tables, so there is no distinction made about which one appears on top or beneath the other.  You will probably have no choice but to use two separate classes and add a z-index for each.  For example - using the same entire class definition for each table:

```
table.outer-table thead tr th {
  position:sticky;
  top:0px;
  height:2em;
  z-index:99;
}

table.inner-table thead tr th {
  position:sticky;
  top:0px;
  height:2em;
  z-index:98;
}
```

I tested this in your JSFiddle page and it seemed to do what you wanted, so it definitely looks like z-index is important here.  If nesting of tables can be extensive, a class could target them using something like:

```
table {z-index:99}
table > table {z-index:98}
table > table > table {z-index:97}
```

ie - a table, a table within a table and a table within a table within a table.

Comment: As hacky as that feels, I definitely like that CSS solution over a JS-based one. That's a good idea, thanks.

Comment: css is easier because you can specify as many nested tables as you like - if there's no table nested that deep, it is simply not applied.